# Is it possible to run git commands without git prefix

Tags: git, ubuntu

As the title says, is it possible to start an *interactive* git shell where all the commands are automatically prefixed by `git`?

So instead of doing:

```
git fetch
git add
git commit
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
git -i  #start the 'interactive' git shell, not the right command obviously

fetch   #does git fetch
add     #does git add
commit  #does git commit

git -x  #exit the 'interactive' git shell
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? `git` is not that much to type (you can create an `alias g=git` to make it even shorter). And how should your shell handle commands such as `ls` or `cd`? But Git does not – to my knowledge – have such a feature.

Comment: @knittl The same way that e.g. `ftp` does it? Assume any command is intended for that program, and if the command is not recognised, issue an error message. I don't see anything in the question that suggests that non-Git commands still need to work.

Comment: @knittl, you can make the shell handle `ls` and `cd` completely normally, but for any unrecognized command try running it with `git` as the prefix.

Comment: What should `rm` do? I can see some small use in having shorter commands to type, but not if it loses the ability to mix `git` commands with non-`git` commands.

Comment: It's not required for this interactive shell to handle non git commands.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think such a mode is in integrated in git. I suggest you to check [`git-sh`](http://rtomayko.github.io/git-sh/). You can configure it to use the aliases you prefer.

Comment: I don't want to use git-sh as i have to redefine all the aliases, i'm looking for a solution, git or another tool, that will let me start an interactive shell and prefix them with 'git',

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Bash shell you can set a "command not found handler" which is a shell function that will be run whenever any command is not recognized. You can use that to try running `git-status` if you run `status` and the shell can't find that command e.g.

```
command_not_found_handle() {
    gitcmd=`git --exec-path`/git-$1 ;
    if type -a $gitcmd >/dev/null  2>&1 ;
    then
        shift ;
        exec $gitcmd "$@" ;
    fi ;
    echo "bash: $1: command not found" >&2 ;
    return 1 ;
}
```

This won't expand `git` aliases, it only recognizes the commands that exist as executables in the `GIT_EXEC_PATH` directory, such as `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-status`

```
master*% src$ pwd
/home/jwakely/src/foo/src
master*% src$ git status -s
 M include/foo.h
?? TODO
master*% src$ status -s      # runs 'git-status -s'
 M include/foo.h
?? TODO
master*% src$ git st         # a git alias
 M include/foo.h
?? TODO
master*% src$ st             # does not recognize git alias
bash: st: command not found
```

If you want it to handle aliases, but with the downside that **any** unrecognized command (including typos) will be passed to Git, you can make it much simpler:

```
command_not_found_handle() { git "$@" ; }

master*% src$ st            # runs 'git st'
 M include/foo.h
?? TODO
master*% src$ statu         # runs 'git statu'
git: 'statu' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
        status
        stage
        stash
```

Comment: This sounds close to what I want, but is there a way to stop non git commands from running? eg: running reset with the above runs normal reset instead of git reset. Is it also possible for these commands to be auto completed?

Comment: Sounds like you want git-sh instead. You _could_ remove everything from your `PATH` and have the command-not-found handler called for every command, and have it invoke `usr/bin/git` (or whatever its absolute path is on your machine). You _could_ configure bash autocompletion to do the same autocompletion for `reset` as it does for `git reset` but it would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

gitsh is, maybe, what are you looking for?

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/announcing-gitsh

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/mchav/With, you can do:

```
with git

> git status
> git log
```

It might need to be accompanied with `rlwrap` so you can navigate history with the arrow keys:

```
rlwrap with git
```

Comment: Check for other options on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555622/prefix-all-commands-in-shell